# How to run this run terraform file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have two terraform files that I need to somehow run, one called terraform-var.tf and one called terraform-build.tf. I've figured that the variable file uses some sort of interpolation to define the variables and thats how the build gets them but I can not seem to actually get the variables loaded. I don't know what commands to run in what order to load the variables then run them.

Heres a example of the two files. 
-terraform-var.tf

```
 variable "access_key" {
      default = "foo"
    }

    variable "secret_key" {
      default = "foo"
    }

    variable "region" {
      default = "us-west-2"
    }
```

-teraform-build.tf

```
   provider "aws" {
      access_key = "${var.access_key}"
      secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
      region     = "${var.region}"
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/build and https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html

Comment: variable names filename should be named with tfvars extension

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have configured the terraform backend appropriately, we need to use **-var-file** as parameter to the terraform apply command.

your apply command should look something like this.

Go to the location where your teraform-build.tf is located

```
terraform apply -var-file="path/to/terraform-var.tfvars"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename your variables file to variables.tf and it should work also.